# Compare Every Record from Two Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Assuming I have two SQL tables consisting of a single column,

i.e.

```
Table 1               Table 2
a1                    a2
b1                    b2
c1                    c2
```

Is there a succinct SQL command to compare each record in one table against each record in the other? (and return true if *any* record from table 1 matches *any* record from table 2)

i.e.

if( a1 = a2 `OR` a1 = b2 `OR` a1 = c2 `OR` b1 = a2 `OR` b1 = b2...)

### I want

If any record from table a matches table b (i.e., in a table of ints, they are the same int), return true.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, just determine if they are the same? Or are you trying in exclude/include based on criteria?

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do. Do you want to see the records where the data is in both tables?

Comment: If any record from table a matches table b (i.e., in a table of ints, they are the same int), return true.

Comment: Pretty sure that my answer below should do exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply

```
if exists (select 1 from T1 inner join TB on T1.Col = T2.Col)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `full join` is well suited to finding differences.  To find rows that are missing in either table:

```
select  *
from    t1
full join    
        t2
on      t1.col1 = t2.col1
where   t1.col1 is null
        or t2.col1 is null
```

This assumes that the single column is unique (i.e. has no duplicate values.)